# Activate CSS Loader onclick with JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a loader which I've found [here](https://loading.io/css/). I would like to show it for 3 seconds after button has been clicked and then make it disappear again.

How can I modify my JS to activate loader for 3 seconds after button has been clicked and then deactivate it?

```js
const loadButton = document.querySelector('.load');

loadButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // activate/deactivate here
});
```

```css
.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.lds-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 8px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}

@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-ring">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<button class="load" onclick="return load()">LOAD</button>
```

Comment: why did you implement querySelector to define click function of button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function load() {
  document.getElementById("loader").classList.add("active");
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("loader").classList.remove("active");
  },3000);
};
```

```css
#loader{
  display:none;
}

#loader.active{
  display:block;
}

.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.lds-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 8px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}

@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <div class="lds-ring">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="load" onclick="load()">LOAD</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, While, your answer itself seems good, I would recommend you read the following to be able to help in the best possible way: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer